# How to map vector of elements into UICollectionView grid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a 1D vector of images (something like 3000) that I want to map into a UICollectionView.  I am having trouble implementing the delegate method cellForItemAtIndexPath -- namely, how do I deal with NSIndex?  I've looked at all the documentation and tutorials on the web, and everybody glosses over this detail: How do I map from this foreign object NSIndex (I don't even know where this comes from) into a single integer index for my array?

As for how the grid should look, one of the following:

(A) Have a preset number X rows of images, with the ability to scroll horizontally by swiping to see the collection.  Ordering should be as such:

```
 1  X+1  2X+1  ...scroll
 2  X+2  3X+2  ...scroll
 .
 .
 X  X+X  2X+X  ...scroll
```

(B) Have a preset number Y columns of images, with the ability to scroll vertically by swiping to see the collection:

```
 1   2   3  ...  Y
Y+1 Y+2 Y+3 ... Y+Y
 .
 .
scroll up and down
 .
 .
```

Do I need dequeueReusableCell of a custom kind?  Subclass my own FlowLayout?  I'm confused because this NSIndex is so baffling.  It's supposed to be a bunch of concatenated integers, it seems, but my data source is a 1D array and I have no idea how to extract the index from NSIndex as the tutorials all use something like assetsArray or 2D array, and documentation of NSIndex just shows a bunch of arrays, not how to use it with a single array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the NSIndexPath from the UICollectionViewDatasouce protocol  is just a Section and Row pair, Not a grid.  Have you implemented the datasource methods *collection:numberOfItemsInSecion* and *numberOfSectionsInCollection*.  You must do these first. The deal with *cellsForItemAtIndexPath*.

So for example in your case, *numberOfItemsInCollection would return 1.  This means that there is only 1 section of data. Then *collection:numberOfItemsInSection would return the count of your 1d array. The indexPath object has a section and row property.  So if your *numberOfItemsInCollection* return 4 (meaning there is 4 sections of data), then the *collection:NumberOfItemsInSection* would be called 4 at least 4 times.  Each time, the indexPath.section would tell you what section of the data does the collectionView need a count for.

In *collection:cellForItemAtIndexPath:* datasource delegate, will be call at least for every item in your 1d array. The indexPath.section will tell you what section of data and indexPath.row will tell you want item.  In your case since you should only have 1 section, indexPath.row will be the index into your 1d array.  ( myarray.objectAt(indexPath.row  or myarray[indexPath.row] )

This Datasource protocol is exactly like UITableViewDatasource.

Once more thing, the UICollectionView has nothing to do with how the grid of items are laid out.  The Layout object does that for you.  If you want a grid of items then use FlowLayout.